# Recreate JSON data in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, feedly

I'm trying to build an app on the Feedly API. In order to be able to mark categories as read, I need to post some data to the API. I'm having no success, though.

This is what the API needs as input:

```
{
  "lastReadEntryId": "TSxGHgRh4oAiHxRU9TgPrpYvYVBPjipkmUVSHGYCTY0=_1449255d60a:22c3491:9c6d71ab",
  "action": "markAsRead",
  "categoryIds": [
    "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/design",
    "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/photography"
  ],
  "type": "categories"
}
```

And this is my method:

```
- (void)markCategoryAsRead: (NSString*)feedID{

    NSLog(@"Feed ID is: %@", feedID);

    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *accessToken = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"AccessToken"];

    NSString *feedUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.feedly.com/v3/markers"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"markAsRead", @"action",
                         @"categories", @"type",
                         @[feedID], @"categoryIds",
                         @"1367539068016", @"asOf",
                         nil];
    NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Postdata is: %@", postdata);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:feedUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [request addValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

    NSError *errror = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errror];

    NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

    if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        NSLog(@"It's marked as read.");
    } else {
        if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", errror);
        NSLog(@"No success marking this as read. %@", response);
    }
}
```

It keeps throwing a `400` error though, saying `bad input`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with `postdata` after creating it. Attach it to the request.

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: I'm such a dumbass. Must've deleted it accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code. Here are some I noticed:

1. You're not using `postData`.
2. The dictionary you make in `tmp` doesn't look like the dictionary you said you wanted to send. Where's `lastReadEntryId`, for example?
3. `NSString *feedUrl` should be `NSURL *feedUrl`
4. Stylistically, you should be using the [dictionary literal syntax](http://cocoaheads.tumblr.com/post/17757846453/objective-c-literals-for-nsdictionary-nsarray) to create your dictionary. This will make it easier to debug.